# Strings in init are not localized

Tags: swiftui, localization

I do localization of my iOS SwiftUI app and using XCode Product/Export localizations.. function to create xcloc file. Everything works fine but strings in init() are not detected in shown in xcloc. Is there any way how to add them?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace all relevant `String` types that are initialized with static string literals with `LocalizedStringKey`, mainly in the `func`s and `init()`s – so for example:

```
struct MyStruct {

    var myVar: LocalizedStringKey

    init(var: LocalizedStringKey) {
        self.myVar = var
    }
    ...
}
```

`String`types in model data have to stay untouched.
If there are missing cases left you can add them manually to your `.strings` file by

```
"original text" = "localized text";
```